# Close application if home button clicked on iOS device

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, typescript

I have a need to close/kill hybrid cordova/angular4 application running on iOS if home button clicked, although I know that apple doesn't want someone to explicitly programatically close application there is a business requirement for project to do so. I don't have problem coming up with how to exit application with simple UI button, but how do I access

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

method from cordova/angular level?

Comment: Maybe the pause event can work for you, The pause event fires when the native platform puts the application into the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added the [`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23) to you apps info.plist and set it to true.

Comment: when you add the key UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend, make sure select value type is Boolean else it wont work.

Comment: If you use Xcode target info page it will select the correct type automatically. But yes make sure the key is of type Boolean.

Comment: I added <config-file parent="UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" target="*-Info.plist">
            <true />
        </config-file> to config.xml, but it doesn't work, maybe you know why?